# Override value from ui-iconpicker Library - Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the following library to be able to select an icon in an input field for angular.

https://github.com/justin-lau/ui-iconpicker

**What I've tried**

```
<!-- Generates iconpicker button -->
<ui-iconpicker ng-model="icon"
               groups="font-awesome">
</ui-iconpicker>

<!-- input field with icon string that will be stored in DB -->
<input ng-model="icon" 
       type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Select Icon" 
       name="icon" 
       disabled>
```

I have this JSON string stored in my database

```
"icon":"fa fa-lg fa-heart"
```

But somehow I can't or don't know how to override the default value from this ui-iconpicker library.

My ng-model `icon` will be set to `fa fa-lg fa-glass` by loading my page again and overrides my `"fa fa-lg fa-heart"`

To get the data I have an initialise function that will get the object with the icon by the way. But that gets ignored or overrided by the library functionality. What I would like is to override this value in the controller again.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, didn't know this would work but it's a simple solution. I thought the library would work without the brackets but guess I was just wrong.

```
<ui-iconpicker ng-model="icon"
               value="<% icon %>" <!-- or use default angular brackets {{ icon }} -->
               groups="font-awesome">
</ui-iconpicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if your have

```
var icon = {"icon":"fa fa-lg fa-heart"};
```

then

```
<ui-iconpicker ng-model="icon.icon"
               groups="font-awesome">
</ui-iconpicker>
```